# Using bootstrap button to toggle bold state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap toggle button should used to toggle div text bold state.

On first click button should remain in checked state and text become bold.
On second click button should remain in unchecked state and text should become normal.
I tried code below but only first click worked.
Second click does not remove bold from text.

How to fix this ?

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#designer-javascript-bold').change(function (e) {
                //         $(this).button('toggle');
                var checked = $(this).val();
                $(".ui-selected").each(function () {
                    $(this).css("font-weight", checked === "on" ? "bold" : "normal");
                });
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="designer-javascript-bold"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-selected">Toggleable text</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are checking the `value` of the input. The `checked` property seems more relevant:

```
var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
```

This will give you a boolean value to use in your ternary:

```
$(this).css("font-weight", checked ? "bold" : "normal");
```

Example:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#designer-javascript-bold').change(function(e) {
        var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
        $(".ui-selected").each(function() {
          $(this).css("font-weight", checked ? "bold" : "normal");
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-info">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="designer-javascript-bold"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-selected">Toggleable text</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use is(":checked") instead of val() (and then test if checked is true or false)

EDIT: Someone gave 3 minutes before me almost the same answer ;) Maybe even in more elegant way.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#designer-javascript-bold').change(function (e) {
                
                var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
             
                $(".ui-selected").each(function () {
                    $(this).css("font-weight", checked ? "bold" : "normal");
                });
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="designer-javascript-bold"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-selected">Toggleable text</div>
</body>
```